# Find the Resistance between Two Terminals

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, resistance, terminal

Let's say R = 49 ohms, and we want to find Req between a and d, how do we do that? Do we have to find Req for the whole circuit?
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like homework without effort.

Comment: However, maybe studying https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_5.html helps.

Comment: My advice for solving this problem is using KCL and imagining that *d* is connected to ground and *a* is connected to 1 volt. Then you'll easily be able to find the total resistance.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I'm not asking anyone to solve the exercise for me, I just need advice

Comment: That's why I gave you a link, it seems a bit like a rectangular version of the triangular delta/star conversions like in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform

Comment: What we can say is that if R was equal to 84 ohms then the R equivalent would be the ultimate answer in the universe = 42.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent resistance is just \$V/I\$ for a source applied across the given terminals.

So you can imagine a voltage or current source connected between terminals `a` and `d`, and use whatever method you like (KVL or KCL) to solve for the current or voltage.

Alternative solution: You can use a symmetry argument to show that if you apply a voltage between `a` and `d`, one of the resistors will have no current through it, and therefore can be removed without changing the circuit. Once this resistor is removed you can use parallel and series combinations to find the equivalent resistance of the remaining resistors.